# ClearCase: Is it possible to deliver or rebase selectively?

Tags: clearcase

1. When delivering stream A to stream B, is it possible only to deliver selected elements (directories to be precise) from A to B?
2. When rebasing a stream A from a baseline B, is it possible only to rebase selected elements (directories to be precise) from B to A?

Comment: Are you using base ClearCase or UCM?

Comment: I am using UCM projects.

Comment: @Damien: with terminology like stream, deliver, rebase: obviously ClearCase UCM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ClearCase UCM:

- what you are delivering are baselines or activities
- what you are rebasing are baselines only.
  (and only baselines coming from the direct parent Stream, at that).

So if you directories or elements are the only items of an activity, and that activity doesn't depend on other activities (which can happen when a deliver to another Stream has already been done: all present activities are "linked together" by a technical baseline), then you can deliver just those items (by delivering only that activity).

If your directories and files are then only difference between the source baseline and the foundation baseline you are about to change on the Stream you are rebasing, you can rebase just those items.

But the fact is: it is difficult to make partial deliveries or rebases with ClearCase.

Answer (score 3):

`cleartool  findmerge` does exactly what you are looking for. You'd need to build a wrapper (ANT/Perl) around it if your list is long.

so  go to the target stream/view context and run `findmerge srcdir –type d –merge -print` to test and replace `-print` with `-exec,-gmerge,-abort` etc. as you need. Just replace `srcdir` with your directory or an iterative list/variable/array in your script.

Find complete details look at http://www.ipnom.com/ClearCase-Commands/findmerge.html