# Clearcase Deliver - Display element log

Tags: clearcase, ibm-rational

In ClearCase GUI during a delivery i can right click and "display element log"; is there a way to export this element log?  I can run via command line but want to export from GUI if possible; maybe even by activity a week or two later.

Answer (score 0):

For a given element during a merge, you can "export" the "display element log" dialog box in that you can copy-paste its content.
That is hardly a scalable solution however.

You could preview a merge (deliver or rebase) with a [`cleartool findmerge -print`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8060290/6309), however that would be limited to directory merges, not file merges.

The only information you got after a deliver is the UCM `deliver_xxxx` activity created automatically during that process and which allows you to get the exact list of files and directories merged during said deliver.
See for instances of that deliver activity "[Describe baseline and expand deliver and rebase activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327917/describe-baseline-and-expand-deliver-and-rebase-activities/9328314#9328314)"
This won't contain the information of each "display element log" though...